# ReportViewer - 401: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have an ASP.NET website that uses the ReportViewer control. The reporting services are on another machine on the local network. This has been working fine for over six months, but all of a sudden I'm getting the following error in my ReportViewer control:

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

As far as I'm aware, nothing has changed on either of these machines, except that I installed the IIS 'URL Rewrite' module for use with another project. Could this be a factor?

Any other assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very odd. I ran out of ideas and just restarted the server to see if it made a difference. It did. I don't know what the problem was, but maybe this'll save someone a few hours trying to fix the same problem.